# How can I isolate a piece of a variable in a batch file, then save it as another variable?

Tags: batch-file, variables, ftp

Is there a way I can use a set command to isolate a few words from a variable given and then save that as another variable to use later?

If I say `cd C:\users`, can I take something like the `C:\users` and save that as a variable?

```
:inputstage
set /p input=Enter command: 
if /i {%input%}=={get} (goto :get)
:get
set %input%==%getfile%
echo %getfile% >>Files to get.txt
call getfiles.bat
goto: inputstage
```

I input the following when it asks me to enter a command: "get index.html" and it then will take index.html and save it to a file called "files to get.txt" then it'll call up a piece of code that will run the command `ftp -s:ftpreceive.bat` that ftp receive file will then go and read the "files to get.txt" and see index.html and place that into the following ftp code get index.html(or whatever file I specify)

Can I get only a part of the `input` variable to become the variable `getfile`?

Comment: You should show the code you are referring to. Also you should be more specific how you want to select what piece. There are several methods to achieve this: parsing with a for /f, string substitution, substrings.

Comment: As you can see it's impossible to clearly read more than one line of code in comments. So please edit your question to include your addendum. (And use the {} above the input box to tag your code.)

Comment: That peace of code doesn't highlight what you want to extract. BTW the if in it's current form is superfluous as code flows to get if the condition isn't met.

Comment: I suggest you read what a [mcve] is.

Comment: i input the following when it asks me to enter a command: "get index.html"
and it then will take index.html and save it to a file called "files to get.txt"
then it'll call up a piece of code that will run the command `ftp -s:ftpreceive.bat` that ftp receive file will then go and read the "files to get.txt" and see index.html and place that into the following ftp code `get index.html(or whatever file i specify)`

Comment: Again, don't put that in a comment but edit your question so other users can help wihtout having to read through all the comments since I'm about to leave the pc for now.

Comment: What do you expect to happen in case the `if` condition (which should actually look like `if /I "%input%"=="get" (goto :get)`) is not fulfilled?

Comment: You never set variable `getfile`. The line `set %input%==%getfile%`, supposing you replace `==` by `=`, takes the value of variable `input` as the name of a variable, which the value of variable `getfile` is assigned to; this is not what you want, I guess. Perhaps you mean `set "getfile=%input%"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to try to separate words from input or separate into `<command>` and `<whatever>`. In both cases, `for` is the way to go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "input=get something special"
echo method 1 (get "first word" and "rest"):
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('echo %input%') do (
  set "command=%%a"
  set "param=%%b"
)
echo %command% : %param%
echo/
echo method2 (get every word):
set i=0
for %%a in (%input%) do (
  set "_var[!i!]=%%a"
  set /a i+=1
)
set _var
```